# having trouble understanding classie.js API

Tags: javascript, classiejs

Hello all I'm working through an example of a slide and push menu on another site and am struggling to understand an if statement in the classie.js file that is included with the source download.

```
if ( 'classList' in document.documentElement ) {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return elem.classList.contains( c );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.add( c );
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.remove( c );
  };
}
else {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return classReg( c ).test( elem.className );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    if ( !hasClass( elem, c ) ) {
      elem.className = elem.className + ' ' + c;
    }
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.className = elem.className.replace( classReg( c ), ' ' );
  };
}
```

I can't seem to wrap my head around the first IF statement.  My understanding is that `document.documentElement` returns the `<html>` tag, but what is that `'classList'` business?  The only thing I can find on it was on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList), but I don't understand at all what that IF statement is testing for. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newer browsers support a `.classList` property on DOM element nodes. It's an array of class names. Older browsers just support the `.className` property, which is a single string containing space-separated class names.

If the `if` statement in the code you posted sees that the document node has a `.classList` property, it knows that it's running on a newer browser. If not, then it creates alternative versions of some class management utilities.

Answer (score 1):

`'classList' in document.documentElement` simply checks for the existence of `classList` within the `document.documentElement` Element.

From [MDN's documentation on the `in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in).

> The `in` operator returns true if the specified property is in the specified object.

Comment: @Pointy yep, fixing that now!